# Better solution than left join subqueries?

Tags: oracle, performance, subquery, left-join, correlated-subquery

```
TablePatient.Patient_ID(PK)

TableProviders.Encounter (joins to PK)

TableProviders.Provider_Type

TableProviders.Provider_ID

TableNames.Full_Name

TableNames.Provider_ID (joins to Table Names)
```

I want a query that will give, for all the `Patient_IDs`, the `Full_Name` of the provider for every `Provider ID`.

There are about 30 `provider_types`.

I have made this already using a left join a ton of left joins.  It takes a long time to run and I am thinking there is a trick I am missing.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my previous answer didn't match at all what you meant. You want to pivot the table to have on each line one `Patient_ID` with every `Full_name` for every `provider_type`. I assume that each patient has only one provider for one type and not more ; if more, you will have more than one row for each patient, and anyway I don't think it's really possible.

Here is my solution with pivot. The first part is to make it more understandable, so I create a table named `TABLE_PATIENT` in a subquery.

```
WITH TABLE_PATIENT AS
(   
SELECT TablePatient.Patient_ID,
TableProviders.Provider_Type,
TableNames.Full_Name


FROM TablePatient LEFT JOIN
TableProviders on TablePatient.Patient_ID = TableProviders.Encounter 
LEFT JOIN
TableNames on TableNames.Provider_ID = TableProviders.Provider_ID

group by TablePatient.Patient_ID,
TableProviders.Provider_Type,
TableNames.Full_Name
)

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_PATIENT
PIVOT
(
    min(Full_name)
    for Provider_type in ([type1], [type2],[type3])
) AS PVT
```

So `TABLE_PATIENT` just has many rows for each patient, with one provider each row, and the pivot puts everything on a single row. Tell me if something doesn't work.

You need to write every type you want in the [type1],[type2] etc. Just put them inside [], no other character needed as ' or anything else.

If you put only some types, then the query will not show providers of other types.

Tell me if something doesn't work.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could you please confirm my answer then ? :)

Comment: Is there a way to add a "CASE" to the output? I tried "*," and also "TABLE_PATIENT.*," and "T.*," after making an alias "T" for "TABLE_PATIENT", but none of that worked.

Comment: The name of the table if not table_patient anymore but PVT, I'm not sure to perfectly understant but try PVT.blabla for the case

Comment: Can't seem to get "Patient_ID" back in the output.  Each row is a unique Patient_ID, but I need to know the value.

Comment: I posed the question in another post.  Maybe you can help. "Find my missing column in joined pivot tables"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you just want to group the answer by Patient Id and then Provider ID. A full name is unique on a provider id right ?

This should be something like

```
SELECT TablePatient.Patient_ID,
TableProviders.Provider_ID,
TableNames.Full_Name


FROM TablePatient LEFT JOIN
TableProviders on TablePatient.Patient_ID = TableProviders.Encounter 
LEFT JOIN
TableNames on TableNames.Provider_ID = TablerProviders.Provider_ID

group by TablePatient.Patient_ID,
TableProviders.Provider_ID,
TableNames.Full_Name
```

You can either group by `TableNames.Full_Name` or  select `First(TableNames.Full_Name)` for example if indeed a full name is unique to a provider ID.

Note : I used the SQL server Syntax, there can be différences with Oracle ..

Comment: Let me clarify:  Every "patient ID" is a row.  There should be one column for every "provider type".  Those columns should contain the "provider full name"

Comment: Is there only one Provider ID for one Provider Type ? Or you can have multiple ID's for only one type ?

Now that you clarify I understand better. You need to do a pivot. Just answer if the relation between provider Id and provider type is unique and I can write the code. Otherwise look for "pivot" on the web

Comment: There are multiple provider types and there are multiple provider IDs.

Comment: Yes, but is the relation between them unique ? Or can you have two ID's for the same provider type ? And in this case, can one patient ID have two provider ID's of the same type ?

Comment: Yes you can have two IDs for the same provider type. No. One patient can only have one of each provider type.